# Why does Firefox fetch the page when I hit the back button?

Tags: firefox, history, browser-cache

Isn't Firefox supposed to display a cached version of the page when I use the back button?   Is there something I can to do prevent Firefox from doing this ?

I understand it makes less sense nowadays to display a caced version of a page, as most of pages are dynamically generated, and the connection is (in my case) fast enough so that it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What makes you think it's not using the cache?

Comment: The page may contain other links or objects which want to be refreshed. Check the page's source.

Comment: There is a slight lag when I hit back, and Firefox is displaying where it is connecting in the status bar.

Comment: @ott-- Could it be a side effect of an extension ?

Comment: If there is JavaScript on the page then this will run when you go _back_ to that page - this could do anything, including communicating with the server (AJAX). This could certainly override the browser cache.

Comment: @Antoine now don't say it's a php page :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the few tests I've tried, Firefox **is** using the browser cache - no additional HTTP requests are even sent to the server.

If it's not using the cache for you then this might be to do with the cache-control headers as sent by the original page you are going back to. (Or your cache is disabled?!)

**EDIT:** Also note (as mentioned in comments) if there is JavaScript on the page then this will run when you go back to that page - this could potentially do anything, including communicating with the server (AJAX). This could certainly override the browser cache, resulting in a stream of HTTP traffic (as seen in the browser status bar).